# ASP.NET generate ID using Eval functinon

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, eval

For each row in GridView i have a HyperLink, and i need to generate different ID´s for each of them. Using Eval doesn´t work properly:

```
<asp:GridView
                ID="ResultTableGvw"
                runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowDataBound="ResultTableGvw_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="ID" DataField="id" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="accountId" DataField="externalId" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="tydeId" DataField="typeId" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Estado" DataField="statusId" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Timestamp do Pedido" DataField="timestampRequest" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operação" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink
                                ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "Id", "OperationManagementHl{0}") %>'
                                runat="server"
                                Text="">
                            </asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

The error is : `The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />`

Comment: It would help if you share what you mean by "doesn't work properly". What is happening?

Comment: Oh sorry, the error is : The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern and it works for me,

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNames" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Names") %>'  Height ="60px" Width ="90%"    CssClass="LabelDesign"   />
```